# Doublets detection and scoring using ElasticSearch

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, lucene, full-text-search

I'm trying to study the feasibility of a content doublets detection microservice backed by ElasticSearch

we have currently PLSQL procedure calculating the levenshtein distance of user input (title + message) against all his previous entries in a PLSQL, this procedure return for each entry the percentage of ressemblance

Is it possible to give ElasticSearch a title + message + user_id, then it loops against all entries to calculate the score for each one or we need to write a plugin for such purpose ?

Comment: You can index "title + message + user_id" in one field as whole, then use fuzzy query (which uses levenshtein) to get top matches sorted by score descending.